# Awk string and add text

Tags: awk

I have an awk statement below, I'm looking to add some text both before and after each output line.

```
grep  "id\": \"http://mysite.com/movies/new/id/" new_id.txt | head -n1217 | awk -F/ ' { print $7 } ' | awk -F\" ' { print $1 } '
```

That gets me a list of the relevant ID's but I need to take each line it outputs and prepend and append some text. How can I do this, with awk? sed?

Comment: consider editing your question to include sample input data, and required output. Too hard to guess what you intend to accomplish here. Based on my interpretation, this could be done with 1 awk program. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

One way to prepend and append lines with `GNU sed`:

Assuming `infile` with data:

```
one
two
three
```

And following `script.sed`:

```
1,$ {
    i\  
Text prepended (line 1)\ 
Text prepended (line 2
    a\  
Text appended (line 1)\ 
Text appended (line 2)
}
```

Run it like:

```
sed -f script.sed infile
```

That yields:

```
Text prepended (line 1)
Text prepended (line 2
one
Text appended (line 1)
Text appended (line 2)
Text prepended (line 1)
Text prepended (line 2
two
Text appended (line 1)
Text appended (line 2)
Text prepended (line 1)
Text prepended (line 2
three
Text appended (line 1)
Text appended (line 2)
```

So, you will need to adapt it to your needs and add it to the end of your pipe chain.

---

**EDIT**: A `sed` one-liner:

```
sed -e 's/^/Text prepended\n/; s/$/\nText appended/' infile
```

Comment: Thanks, looking more for a single one line command rather than a script.

Comment: @Tony: Updated with the one-liner script.

Comment: This is not an awk solution.